# Question about setting up Google Analytics with Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-workspace, google-analytics

At the bottom of vendor profile, there is an text box for you to insert your GA code.

[image]

Question: what does this do? What kind of stats am I expected to see in Google Analytics? I don't have the luxury of trial and error at the moment.

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/features.html

Comment: What should I be looking at?

Comment: Just it just show referrals?

Comment: @naithemilkman First of all, this question is off topic here as you can read in the FAQ: http://superuser.com/faq - second of all, the "features" page shows you exactly what Google Analytics does for you. Nobody will be able to tell you more about it than Google itself.

Comment: ok close it then

Comment: Take a look at their [Product Tour](http://www.google.com/analytics/tour.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you list your Google Apps domain at your Google Analytics account, a key is generated (as your picture is showing: UA-??????-?)

This code can be entered into your Google Sites, to monitor web site behaviour:
[image]

If you enter this code for the vendors Marketplace app, then user behavior on document level, intranet level or web site level can be monitored.